# Cloud Functions for Firebase - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

The following code executed when something is written at a certain location in the database.

***What I expect from this code :*** If the number of coins are => 500 to subtract **only once** 500 coins from the current coins value and to add **one ticket** to the existing ticket value.

***What I am getting in reality:*** The code recursively subtracts 500 coins until the coin value is lower than 500; It adds more tickets then it should.

Please , can somebody modify my code to work as expected ? 
I do not know what I am doing wrong

```
exports.TransformCoinsIntoTickets1 = functions.database.ref('/AddTickets/{userid}').onWrite(event => {
var user = event.params.userid;


/// first get coins to see if we can lower coin value
var usercoinRef1 = admin.database().ref('coins').child(user);

usercoinRef1.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var numberofcoins = snapshot.val();
   console.log("We are in snapshot of coins -> He has coins = " + numberofcoins);

                                          if (numberofcoins >= 500 )  
                                          return usercoinRef1.set(numberofcoins-500).then(() => {

                                           var ticketRef1 = admin.database().ref('tickets').child(user);

                                            ticketRef1.on("value", function(snap123) {
                                                  var numberoftickets = snap123.val();
 return ticketRef1.set(numberoftickets+1).then(() => {

                                                console.log('Tickets Write succeeded!');
 });

                                                        }, function (error) {
                                                           console.log("Error Tickets: " + error.code);
                                                        });

                                              console.log('Coins Write succeeded!');
                                                         });

}, function (error) {
   console.log("Error Coins: " + error.code);
});


//then we write the new coin value if we need to

 });
```

Comment: Reformat your code :)

Comment: @d9ngle sorry for the bad format :)

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that instead of

> on

i should use

> once

So, replacing

> .on("value",

with

> .once("value",

resolved the problem.